# 30 day name change restriction for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried searching this on google and looking at the question-answer websites like this one, looking at Youtube for answers, But had no luck, so I decided to make this question here. So... I want to change my username in Minecraft before 30 days, and I don't know what to do. I know that there are already questions like this but still I want to know what people will say to this one.

Comment: You can't.You must wait the 30 days.

Comment: :( i find a lot of videos about changing ur name without waiting 30 days but when i click on them they r for Windows not Mac (i use a mac) even if i search with the word 'Mac' with it..

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, you'll have to wait the 30 days. Unless, of course, you wanna shell out $27 for a new account.

Comment: Having multiple accounts for the same user might be in contradiction with Mojangs terms of service though.